# Incompatible types: required T found T Android Studio

Tags: java, generics

I'm using a generics that extends a class:

```
public <T extends Model> List<T> findAll() {
    ...
}
```

The lint checker aways show those errors (unless I remove `<T extends Model>`):

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally import a `Model` class from some other package?

Comment: No, this method is inside the Model class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the class implementing `findAll` must be a parameterized class as well, and here is the signature you must have used (more or less):

```
public class TheClass<T> {

    private List<T> cachedObjects:

    public <T extends Model> List<T> findAll() {

    }

}
```

The problem is that the `T` of `findAll` *overrides* the `T` of the class. Simply use another name for the parameter of your method:

```
public <U extends Model> List<U> findAll() {

}
```

Or do not parameterize your method:

```
public List<T> findAll() {

}
```